# `npm install` installs all dependencies of my project over the network, even if they are already installed or available from cache

Tags: node.js, npm

whenever I run `npm install` in my project directory, npm fetches and installs all dependencies even if they're already installed in `node_modules`. Npm does not install from my cache in `~/.npm/`, even though there are already an extremely large number of packages in my cache.

Here is my npm config settings from `npm config ls -l`:

```
; cli configs
long = true
registry = "https://registry.npmjs.org/"

; userconfig /Users/jay/.npmrc
username = "jayhendren"

; globalconfig /Users/jay/local/nodejs/etc/npmrc
global = true
globalconfig = "/Users/jay/local/nodejs/etc/npmrc"
globalignorefile = "/Users/jay/local/nodejs/etc/npmignore"
prefix = "/Users/jay/local/nodejs"

; default values
always-auth = false
bin-links = true
browser = null
ca = null
cache = "/Users/jay/.npm"
cache-lock-retries = 10
cache-lock-stale = 60000
cache-lock-wait = 10000
cache-max = null
cache-min = 10
cert = null
color = true
depth = null
description = true
dev = false
editor = "/usr/bin/vim"
; email = "" (overridden)
engine-strict = false
fetch-retries = 2
fetch-retry-factor = 10
fetch-retry-maxtimeout = 60000
fetch-retry-mintimeout = 10000
force = false
git = "git"
git-tag-version = true
group = 20
heading = "npm"
https-proxy = null
ignore-scripts = false
init-module = "/Users/jay/.npm-init.js"
init.author.email = ""
init.author.name = ""
init.author.url = ""
init.license = "ISC"
json = false
key = null
link = false
local-address = undefined
loglevel = "http"
; long = false (overridden)
message = "%s"
node-version = "v0.10.25"
npat = false
onload-script = false
optional = true
parseable = false
production = false
proprietary-attribs = true
proxy = null
rebuild-bundle = true
registry = "https://registry.npmjs.org/"
rollback = true
save = false
save-bundle = false
save-dev = false
save-optional = false
searchexclude = null
searchopts = ""
searchsort = "name"
shell = "/bin/zsh"
shrinkwrap = true
sign-git-tag = false
strict-ssl = true
tag = "latest"
tmp = "/var/folders/sq/ls98jmdd09l__xwpxq3qqmpw0000gn/T/"
umask = 18
unicode = true
unsafe-perm = true
usage = false
user = "nobody"
user-agent = "node/v0.10.25 darwin x64"
userconfig = "/Users/jay/.npmrc"
; username = "" (overridden)
version = false
versions = false
viewer = "man"
```

Does anybody know why npm insists on fetching new packages over and over and over again?

Comment: adding the `--skip-installed` flag works, however, I can't find a config option that corresponds to "skip installed". Furthermore, I can't find any info on `--skip-installed` in the npm help or man pages. Do you know where I can find info on this flag? 

This also suggests that npm not installing from cache is a separate problem from npm not skipping installed packages.

Edit: whoops, it appears that the person I was responding to deleted his/her comment.

Comment: I'm not sure the exact reason, but one option may be to specify what modules are bundled with the application via the `package.json` file and [`bundledDependencies`](https://npmjs.org/doc/json.html#bundledDependencies)

Comment: Thanks, Kevin, but the `package.json` file is part of reversion control for this project, so it is identical to the `package.json` file on other machines where npm behaves as expected. Furthermore, npm behaves this way with all projects and global packages on this machine, so I do not believe `package.json` to be an issue.

Answer (score 4):

Use the `prefer-offline` flag to install packages from cache if available and download otherwise like the following:

```
$ npm --prefer-offline install
```

See the [documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/using-npm/config?v=true#prefer-offline).

Answer (score 0):

Use a combination of flags to emulate `skip-installed`

```
global = false
link = true
```

```
foo
+-- node_modules
    +-- blerg (1.2.5) <---[A]
    +-- bar (1.2.3) <---[B]
    |   `-- node_modules
    |       +-- baz (2.0.2) <---[C]
    |       |   `-- node_modules
    |       |       `-- quux (3.2.0)
    |       `-- asdf (2.3.4)
    `-- baz (1.2.3) <---[D]
        `-- node_modules
            `-- quux (3.2.0) <---[E]
```

**References**

[npm 1.0:link](https://nodejs.org/en/blog/npm/npm-1-0-link/)

[npm 1.0:Global vs Local installation](https://nodejs.org/en/blog/npm/npm-1-0-global-vs-local-installation/)

[npm-folders](https://www.npmjs.org/doc/files/npm-folders.html)

[node.js global objects](http://nodejs.org/api/globals.html)

Comment: Has anyone got this to work? Mine produces an error.

Answer (score -1):

I ran "npm prune" inside my project, to remove unnecessary packages (i.e., that were *not* dependencies, and give you that irritating "extraneous" error message). One side effect seemed to be to remove the kind of redundant package you are talking about. For example, gulp requires the gulp-util package. Since that was already at the "top" level, it was removed from gulp's own node-modules.

Comment: Thanks for the answer; this is useful information. But I'm sorry, this doesn't really address the problem at hand, so I'm downvoting this answer.